# What's the best index fill factor for encrypted identifiers?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Let's say you have a non-unique encrypted identifier that is a FK used in queries. In order to improve performance of said queries, you want to create a non-clustered index on that field, which is VARCHAR(20).

The table does not receive any updates to the existing table. There however are a lot of inserts that happen on said table that may insert new or existing encrypted identifiers to the table. The amount of new records inserted could be millions of records per day.

The existing index fill factor is 0, which is 100% of the page being full. This approach increases query performance, but dramatically decreases insert performance while increasing fragmentation.

What would be the best fill factor for this non-clustered index? 70%?

I ask because I do a lot of rebuilds recently because dropping and rebuilding is the only way to improve insert performance.

Comment: This question was asked on dba.stackexchange [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23623/best-value-for-fill-factor-in-index). You can probably take some advice from the several answers there.

Comment: Not specifically for this type of data? That's general fill factor question. Fill factor settings don't apply to all types of data do they?

Comment: It is general advice yes. But I've only known people talking about fill factors in terms of DML, not really types of data. I would recommend the 3 steps as outlined by Edward in the link I gave you.